# Lazy Load delay

Tags: jquery, lazy-loading

I'm using Mika Tuupola's [Lazy Load](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload), which is excellent, but need to delay loading even when image above the fold...

So, user scrolls, when image in view I want to delay 400ms then show the image.

There is a way to increase threshold so images load before shown, but not other way.

I've searched docs on github and can't find a way to do this without reinventing wheels.

Has anyone done this? I know it might seem strange but there's a valid reason for wanting to do it.

Comment: Why do you want to do that if I may ask. The whole idea behind it is that it loads under the fold.

Comment: Sure... I am loading images which users add themselves, each image comes from a different place, I want to briefly show where the image came from and then fade the image in over the top of where it came from

Answer (score -1):

From the [docs](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload):

[image]

I assume you can bind the `scroll` event instead of `load` and it would work just the same.